# ASP.NET MVC - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Pais'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this problem when I send data from View to Controller,

my View:

```
@model Projeto_P1.Models.Cidade
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Cidades";
 }

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCidade", "Geral", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Cidade")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("País")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pais, (SelectList)ViewData["pais"], "Selecione", new { id = "PaisID"})
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Estado")
                @Html.DropDownList("Estado", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Selecione")
            </div>

            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PaisID").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ListaEstados",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { ID: $(this).val() },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var elements = "";
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        elements = elements + '<option values="' + this.id + '">' + this.Nome + '</option>'
                    })
                    $('#Estado').empty().attr('disabled', false).append(elements);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

my Controller, I have have an action AddCidade() that send a SelectList of countrys, an action ListaEstados that returns states, bases on selected country by ajax.

```
    public ActionResult AddCidade()
    {
        ViewData["pais"] = new SelectList(Util.getPais().ToList(), "ID", "Nome");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListaEstados(String id)
    {
        return Json(Util.getEstados(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCidade(Cidade c)
    {
        c.Cadastrar(c);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename the `pais` key because it matches the model's `Pais` property name: `ViewData["anyOtherKeyName"] = ...`, `...(SelectList)ViewData["anyOtherKeyName"]...`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to reinitialize your viewdata in your [HttpPost] method or replace it's return View(); with return RedirectToAction("AddCidade");

Comment: Hi, tks for you answer it works, but now I have other problem, when I send data to Action in controller to persist data, in the dropdown Estado, the HTML code stay like this: <option values="undefined">state name</option> in method that return states I put ID in sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `pais` key because it matches the model's `Pais` property name:

```
ViewData["anyOtherKeyName"] = new SelectList(Util.getPais().ToList(), "ID", "Nome");

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pais, (SelectList)ViewData["anyOtherKeyName"], "Selecione", new { id = "PaisID"})
```

Also you have to save the `PaisID` variable before calling to `$.ajax` function, because `this` doesn't refer to the select anymore:

```
$("#PaisID").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ListaEstados",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { ID: id },
        ...
    });
});
```